# Register context menu verbs for specific file types

Tags: c#, registry, contextmenu, windows-10

I'm registering extended verbs for all video file types on my system by doing something like this:

```
        foreach (var ext in FileTypes.VideoTypes)
        {
            var progId = Registry.GetValue($@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.{ext}", null, null);

            if (progId == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            Registry.SetValue(
                $@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\{progId}\shell\dlsub",
                null,
                "Download subtitle");

            Registry.SetValue(
                $@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\{progId}\shell\dlsub\command",
                null,
                @"""D:\myapp.exe"" ""%1""");
        }
```

Resulting in something like this (`mpeg_auto_file` for `mkv`):

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpg_auto_file\shell\dlsub]
@="Download subtitle"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mpg_auto_file\shell\dlsub\command]
@="\"D:\\myapp.exe\" \"%1\""
```

and `mplayerc.mp4` for `mp4`:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mplayerc.mp4\shell\dlsub]
@="Download subtitle"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mplayerc.mp4\shell\dlsub\command]
@="\"D:\\myapp.exe\" \"%1\""
```

The problem is that the registered verb shows up for `mkv` (and a couple of other filetypes), but the context menus for the other file types (like `mp4`) are unaffected. Adding my verb to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell` does work for these filetypes, but this is obviously not what I want!

Any ideas on the difference between these filetypes? Perhaps it has something to do with the registered ProgID (all `mplayerc` types do not seem to work...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value (aka `ProgId`) that can be found for specific file extension doesn't always point to correct class (the one that will affect menu entries). During my tests, even on fresh copy of Windows 10 - `WMP11.AssocFile.AVI` is a `ProgId` for `.avi` file extension, however when added entry in `WMP11.AssocFile.AVI\Shell\` (either `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`) it didn't affect menu at all. I was about to give up but then i found that `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.avi\OpenWithProgids` store few more values, including `WMP11.AssocFile.AVI` but also other that starts with word App, i.e. `AppX6eg8h5sxqq90pv53845wmnbewywdqq5h`. By editing `Shell\` for that one, i was able to add menu entry. The downside was - it also affected other file extensions that are somehow linked with `AppX6eg8h5sxqq90pv53845wmnbewywdqq5h`. I couldn't accept solution that would force me to iterate through all classes found in `OpenWithProgids`, plus my menu entry had to be shown only for very specific file extensions and not the other. I decided to go with `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex` and DLLs that create menu entry dynamically, based on clicked file type (check for extension).

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. After messing around for a long time, I wound up using `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\<.ext>` instead, which seems to work consistently for me...